# Sed command does not have the same effect when invoked by a Makefile

Tags: bash, sed, makefile

I'm trying to build a generic non-recursive Makefile, with auto-generation of the dependencies (using gcc preprocessor)(as described here : http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/#combine.
I'm trying to make it in a way that would make possible to use 'make' from anywhere in my projects trees. To do so, I'm using a tracking variable $(DIR), and local submakefiles in each directory, as described here https://evbergen.home.xs4all.nl/nonrecursive-make.html

All the generated files are generated in their local directory, so that they can be available from any level of the project tree.

This includes the dependencies files.
The output of the gcc preprocessor(with the flags `-MT $(notdir $@) -MP -MMD -MF file.d.tmp` looks like :

```
target.o: target.c includefile.h includefile2.h

includefile.h:

includefile2.h:
```

Now, i would like to append to the beginning of each word in that dependency file `$(DIR)` (not expanded), so that every time that file is included, the variable is expanded and allow make to correctly locate the file from wherever it has been invoked.

So I wrote a sed command `sed -E "s/[a-z],_,.,:]+/\$(DIR)&/g" file.d.tmp > file.d` to do this.

In the makefile the command is written that way (with an extra $ on $(DIR) to not expand it) and contained in a variable for more readability

`sed -E "s/[a-z],_,.,:]+/\$$(DIR)&/g" file.d.tmp > file.d`

Now, here is my problem :
When I used that sed command on the terminal, it does what I expect : add a $(DIR) to the beginning of each word.
But when I run the Makefile, and it runs the same sed command (which is printed in the correct way, so it does not seems to be an expansion problem inside the Makefile), it does nothing. (and my file.d looks the same way that my file.d.tmp)

If you have some leads on this, I would be grateful ;)

P.S: There are the complete parts of Makefile concerned:

```
DEPFLAGS = -MT $@ -MP -MMD -MF $(word 2,$^).tmp

COMPILE = $(CC) $(DEPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
POSTCOMPILE = sed -E "s/[a-z],_,.,:]+/\$$(DIR)&/g" $(word 2,$^).tmp > $(word 2,$^)
```

and the implicit rule:

```
%.o: %.c
%.o: %.c %.d
    $(COMPILE)
    $(POSTCOMPILE)
```

Comment: Two comments: 1. are you sure that the implicit rule `%.o: %.c %.d` is really executed? I had to resort to the first rule, where `$(word 2,$^)` is empty, due to the lack of `%.d`. Then I had to use $(subst .cpp,.d,$^)
 
2. I am not sure when the POSTCOMPILE is evaluated and if $^ is empty at that point in time. Try to use `sed -E "s/[a-z],_,.,:]+/\$$(DIR)&/g" $(subst .cpp,.d,$^).tmp > $(subst .cpp,.d,$^)` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where exactly the difference comes from, but here are two suggestions:

1) Since it seems like you don't want expansion at all, simply use single quotes, instead of jumping through hoops to escape stuff

2) Your character class specification seems to be wrong, did you mean `[a-z_.:]`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how `sed -E "s/[a-z],_,.,:]+/\$(DIR)&/g" file.d.tmp > file.d` can work when you run it from a shell prompt.  The character class `[a-z],_,.,:]+` is not right, because it means `[a-z]` (a single character a through z) followed by the literal caracters `,_,.,:]+` which I assume you don't have in your output file.

I would have thought you'd want something like:

```
sed -E "s/[]a-z,_.:]+/\$(DIR)&/g" file.d.tmp > file.d
```

The close bracket coming right after the open bracket includes the bracket in the character class, it doesn't close it.  See the docs for regex.  Also you don't need to include the comma multiple times.

Comment: That was indeed the regex that was ill-written ; i've how it was working.

Comment: i've no idea how it was working like that. I tested it on another system (the first was MacOS, the second Linux) and that time it did not work.
As shinobi infered, `[a-z_.:]`was what I wanted.